# Showing runtime error in WebDriver dri = new ChromeDriver();

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Showing runtime error in WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

I have written the code as

```
public class a1_Google {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{ 
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\nuzee\\IdeaProjects\\Selenium\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");         
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

It is showing as this in console

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 111.0.5563.64 (c710e93d5b63b7095afe8c2c17df34408078439d-refs/branch-heads/5563@{#995}) on port 56069
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Mar 16, 2023 3:44:26 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Mar 16, 2023 3:44:26 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError
WARNING: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden
java.io.IOException: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.WebSocketHandler.abort(WebSocketHandler.java:92)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.WebSocketHandler.handleRead(WebSocketHandler.java:118)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.AsyncHttpClientHandler.channelRead(AsyncHttpClientHandler.java:78)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:311)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:432)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to establish websocket connection to http://localhost:57471/devtools/browser/43a48509-4ce9-4f3f-80c6-4ec40faba4d5
Build info: version: '4.1.1', revision: 'e8fcc2cecf'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-NMB8SION', ip: '192.168.0.107', os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '18.0.1.1'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.<init>(NettyWebSocket.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.lambda$create$3(NettyWebSocket.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.openSocket(NettyClient.java:118)
    at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:77)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.lambda$new$2(ChromiumDriver.java:124)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:46)
    at PracticePrograms.a1_Google.main(a1_Google.java:12)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Tried to initialize chrome driver but it is showing error and not getting initialized

Answer (score -2):

Change the below code:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

To:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: 5 different questions with the same issue in the last few days, would be better to flag it as a duplicate.